# How to show Appdynamics generated error logs in MS Team channel

Tags: json, microsoft-teams, webhooks, appdynamics

Can some one advise, how to show appdynamics generated business transactions error logs or stack tace logs in MS Team channel with webhook. And also please asvise what is JSON payload script, we can use it for.

Comment: Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet